# saving a file input as distance matrix in R

Tags: r, distance

I have a file which contains data as distance matrix. It looks like this:

```
['1.2033','1.1100','1.2200']
['1.1100','1.0890']
['0.2233']
```

where first row represents the distance between a and b, a and c, a and d. Second shows distance between b and c and b and d and third is between c and d.

I want to save it as a distance matrix in R. Can someone help me with that? That is extract these numbers and save them as a distance matrix in R?

Comment: Perhaps `lines <- readLines("yourfile.txt");read.table(text=gsub("[][]|'", "", lines), sep=",", header=FALSE, fill=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks, this saves it as a table but not as distance matrix. when I apply as.dist() function on it, it gives me error that NA values not allowed

Comment: Please check the dupe link.